# Does subtracting a rank-1 matrix from a positive definite matrix result in positive semi-definite matrix?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite, hessian-matrix

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive definite matrix. We define the matrix $B$ as follows:

\begin{equation} 
B = A - \frac{1}{e^\top A e} Aee^\top A
 \end{equation}

where $e=(1,1,...,1)$.

I believe that $B$ is positive semi-definite, but I am unable to prove it.

Comment: What have you tried? I think that this should be reasonable to prove using the definition + Cauchy-Schwarz. Happy to elaborate further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) there exists a matrix $L$ such that $A=LL^\top$.
Then,
$$v^\top B v = v^\top A v - \frac{(v^\top A e)^2}{e^\top A e}
= \|L^\top v\|^2 - \frac{((L^\top v)^\top (L^\top e))^2}{\|L^\top e\|^2}.$$
Now use Cauchy-Schwarz to show that this quantity is nonnegative.